# space complexity when a vector is copied

Tags: space-complexity

what will be the space complexity of this class? and why?
what will be the space complexity used by the function moveZeroes

```
class Solution {
    
public:
    
        void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
            vector<int>nums2(nums);
            int j=0;
            int numOfZeros=0;
            for(int i=0;i<nums2.size();i++){
                if(nums2[i]!=0){
                    nums[j]=nums2[i];
                    j++;
                }
                else{
                    numOfZeros++;
                }
            }
            for (int k =numOfZeros; k >0 ; k--)
            {
                 nums[j]=0;
                 j++;
            } 
       }
};
```

Comment: Hi, Are you sure about this line? `if(nums2[i]!=0){`. `if(nums[i]!=0){` makes more sense to me...